# Is there a source code formatter for Groovy?

Tags: formatting, groovy

I use the commercial version of Jalopy for my Java projects but it doesn't work on Groovy files.  IntelliJ has a serviceable formatter but I don't like requiring a particular IDE.

Comment: groovy is a language, implemented on the JVM. see groovy.org . 

Groovy is a superset of the java lanaguage apparently.

Comment: The comment about Groovy being a superset of Java is inaccurate. For example, Groovy doesn't support inner classes (yet).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Try "BUSL"

**2022-10-26 NOTE:** HISTORIC. "BUSL" seems to be dead. [Last archived webpage is from 2020](https://web.archive.org/web/20200701144255/http://busl.tigris.org/).

I've found that [BUSL](http://busl.tigris.org/) works really well on Groovy files. It's standalone too, so you can use it from your text editor or whatever.

Comment: FWIW, BUSL appears to be mostly dead. It had a "beta" release in 2005 and no activity since.

Comment: BUSL has dropped off the internet

Answer (score 5):

## Try npm-groovy-lint

You can use `npm-groovy-lint` via command line with `--format` option :)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-groovy-lint

Comment: Sadly npm-groovy-lint has many bugs with the prettifier.

Comment: I encountered four parse problems with npm-groovy-lint, and it didnt say which files where a problem, whereas I had one parse problem with spotless which was easy to isolate as it told me which file caused the java exception.

Comment: After figuring out there is nothing public right now exists I've created my own small dependency free library to do it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/groovy-beautify

Answer (score 4):

[spidasoftware/format](https://github.com/spidasoftware/format) extracts the groovy eclipse plugin and provides a command line interface to it.

Instructions:

```
git clone git@github.com:spidasoftware/format.git && \
cd format/bin && \
./format /path/to/groovy/file
```

caveat: this project is no longer maintained however still works as of the time of this post

Comment: This is a wrapper around https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/blob/master/ide/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring/src/org/codehaus/groovy/eclipse/refactoring/formatter/DefaultGroovyFormatter.java .  spotless is also a wrapper around this.

Answer (score 2):

the latest eclipse plugin will do some formatting and refactoring: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Eclipse+Plugin+Refactoring

Answer (score 2):

Groovy support for Jalopy is coming later this year. There is a tiny sneak preview on YouTube showcasing the Eclipse plug-in:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNFUzvOZei0

Comment: That's what the OP said he used already.

Comment: Groovy isnt mentioned on their website https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=groovy+site%3Atriemax.com

Answer (score 2):

## Older groovyc had some formatter

**2022-10-26 NOTE:** HISTORIC. The formatter seems to have disappeared in newer versions. See comment.

Actually `groovyc` came with a builtin formatter (kind of). If you set the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` to `-Dantlr.ast` and run `groovyc test.groovy` a file called test.groovy.pretty.groovy is generated.

But be aware: From what I found in the internet about this, this formatter is not configurable and strips comments!

Comment: Using v3.0.8, this doesnt appear to work anymore

Answer (score 2):

[Spotless](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless) also formats groovy. Seems to be impossible to run without gradle/maven though. :(

Answer (score 1):

I have yet to find a good solution for this, and I really wish that there was one. Regarding @Gizmomogwai's tip, it doesn't exactly work as you'd think.

First of all, you need to export `JAVA_OPTS=-Dantlr.ast:groovy`. However, the file produced by `groovyc` is clearly not "pretty" in the sense that it is pretty to humans. The "pretty" output generates a file which will be parsed by the next stage of the compiler. Effectively, this means that it not only strips comments but also will add and alter newlines and whitespace. It is definitely *not* suitable for checking code formatting.